# How to create periodic automatic reboot with jobs prior and after reboot?

Tags: server, cron, minecraft

Currently I have a Minecraft server running on a remote PC with Ubuntu server 22.04.1. I would like to create a job which would restart the PC itself while properly shutting down Minecraft server prior to reboot afterwards it should execute /opt/minecraft/run.sh inside a newly created screen session. I am very fresh into Linux and it was my first project with it.

Comment: see the "The systemd service file" part of the minecraft installer. that unit will allow you to start, stop,and restart your minecraft server.  see for instance https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Server_startup_script

Comment: Thank you I will look into it but how would I do periodic restarts of the whole PC.